# GA4: Measurement API can't add correctly?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I'm using the measurement-api to send e-commerce-transactions to Google Analytics 4 like this:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-xxxxxxxx&api_secret=xxxxxxxxxx

Post-Data:
array(3) {
  ["client_id"]=>
  string(21) "xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx"
  ["events"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "purchase"
      ["params"]=>
      array(10) {
        ["currency"]=>
        string(3) "EUR"
        ["transaction_id"]=>
        string(5) "123456"
        ["shipping"]=>
        string(4) "0.00"
        ["tax"]=>
        string(5) "37.88"
        ["value"]=>
        string(6) "237.25"
        ["items"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(7) {
            ["item_id"]=>
            string(11) "ItemId1"
            ["item_name"]=>
            string(70) "xxxx"
            ["index"]=>
            int(1)
            ["item_brand"]=>
            string(9) ""
            ["item_category"]=>
            string(22) "..."
            ["price"]=>
            string(6) "186.58"
            ["quantity"]=>
            float(1)
          }
          [1]=>
          array(7) {
            ["item_id"]=>
            string(10) "ItemId2"
            ["item_name"]=>
            string(51) "xxxxx"
            ["index"]=>
            int(2)
            ["item_brand"]=>
            string(9) ""
            ["item_category"]=>
            string(22) "..."
            ["price"]=>
            string(5) "50.67"
            ["quantity"]=>
            float(1)
          }
        }        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The sum of the transaction is 237.25 (186.58 + 50.67). But: In GA4 this transaction shows up with a turnout of 237.73. This does happen only to some of our transactions, but not all, but the result is that the daily numbers don't match the values in our shop.

Any idea what the problem might be? We double-checked that we are not sending additional transaction with the same transaction_id. We send the same transaction to Analytics Universal and there the correct value shows up (237.25).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your using your price data as strings. Make sure you convert them to integers before adding them to the dataLayer. number_format($yourPrice->getValue(), 2, '.', ',');

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm already using number_fomat, which returns a string, this is why a string is sent. Should I insert the double-values right away like $yourPrice->getValue() (without number_format)?